# How I can change div class over Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying the follow thing:
If I check radio button (id green) the div class "app-bar" should be replaced with the div class "app-bar green". I have tried with the following code, but somehow it doesnt works. Can someone help me?

JavaScript code:

```
var defaulttheme = document.getElementById("default");
var greentheme = document.getElementById("green");
if (defaulttheme.checked) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("app-bar").className = "app-bar";
} else if (greentheme.checked) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("app-bar").className = "app-bar green";
}
```

Code of the radio buttons:

```
<label class="switch">
    <input type="radio" class="checkbox" name="portion_num" id="default" checked>
    <span class="check"></span>
</label>
<label class="switch">
    <input type="radio" class="checkbox" name="portion_num" id="green">
    <span class="check"></span>
</label>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TSeZ.png)

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection.  You need to parse that collection and set the classname for each individually.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0):

I believed you want it to be like this? The `className` property is only available when you target a certain index of the returned array list of elements with class `app-bar`.

```js
var defaulttheme = document.getElementById("default");
var greentheme = document.getElementById("green");
defaulttheme.addEventListener('change',update);
greentheme.addEventListener('change',update);

function update(){
  if (defaulttheme.checked) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("app-bar")[0].className = "app-bar";
  } else if (greentheme.checked) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("app-bar")[0].className = "app-bar green";
  }
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
    <input type="radio" class="checkbox" name="portion_num" id="default" checked>
    <span class="check"></span>
</label>
<label class="switch">
    <input type="radio" class="checkbox" name="portion_num" id="green">
    <span class="check"></span>
</label>

<div class="app-bar">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for your example which returns the first  matched element element within the document and then you can use Element.className property on the that element to set the class attribute.

document.getElementsByClassName() returns a  live HTMLCollection of found elements and you will have to use index/loop to first get the element and then use Element.className property to set the class attribute.

```js
var defaulttheme = document.getElementById("default");
var greentheme = document.getElementById("green");

defaulttheme.addEventListener("click", themeChange);
greentheme.addEventListener("click", themeChange);


function themeChange() {
  if (defaulttheme.checked) {
    document.querySelector(".app-bar").className = "app-bar";
  } else if (greentheme.checked) {
    document.querySelector(".app-bar").className = "app-bar green";
  }
}
```

```css
div.app-bar {
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
}
div.app-bar.green {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-bar">
</div>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="radio" class="checkbox" name="portion_num" id="default" checked>
  <span class="check"></span>
</label>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="radio" class="checkbox" name="portion_num" id="green" >
  <span class="check"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it!

Comment: @Steve Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

To get the element by JavaScript, you have two ways:

`element = document.getElementByClassName("app-bar");`
Or I prefer this way:
`element = document.querySelector(".app-bar");`
Then, you don't change "app-bar" into "app-bar green", but you add the class "green". You can do this by this code:
`element.classList.add("green")`.
So, we can have this code:

```js
var defaulttheme = document.getElementById("default");
var greentheme = document.getElementById("green");

if (greentheme.checked) {
    document.querySelector(".app-bar").classList.add("green");
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
    <input type="radio" class="checkbox" name="portion_num" id="default" checked>
    <span class="check"></span>
</label>
<label class="switch">
    <input type="radio" class="checkbox" name="portion_num" id="green">
    <span class="check"></span>
</label>
```